# Web browser internals

Tags: javascript, web, browser, rendering

Which component of the browser is responsible to construct a DOM tree and where does this DOM tree exist? Rendering engine or JavaScript engine?

Do i understand it correct that, the rendering engine constructs the DOM tree in-memory in whatever language the rendering engine is written in and exposes an API for JavaScript to modify it? Does JavaScript engine create JavaScript objects like HTMLAnchorElement object e.g. that matches one-on-one to the DOM tree constructed by the rendering engine?

Comment: DOM is part of browser engine , which exposes js api as you suggest. Suggest you go to MDN docs for more technical answers

Comment: dom and rendering are separate; dom is there without CSS...

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

Answer (score 0):

Please see below link.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/

There are Five Components that plays vital role in browser

1. Network
2. Parser
3. Format
4. Layout
5. Display (Paint and Composition  togetherly called display.

I Parser is the component who is responsible to construct a DOM tree. There are lot of parsers in the browsers to name a few (HTML, XHTML, SVG, CSS etc...).
Hope this helps.